# How can I force angular binding to update the view

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I am adding a "loading task" in my html so I can update some `{{loading_task}}` when I am going to some slow route or loading some data from remote so I can keep the user interface more informative about what the current task is about in the system.

In my controller, I am simply updating the `$rootScope.loading_task` with a string in order to achieve this.

In my html, I have just

```
<h3 ng-model="loading_task">{{loading_task}}</h3>
```

Say I have couple messages:

```
1. loading
2. configuring
3. calculating
```

When I `ctrl` + `f5` the page, I can the see the message updated only once from loading to configuring. Configuring is loading a big JS file from remote in a callback. So it works. While calculating is doing a lot of DOM event triggering. This basically seems not working at all. I am thinking it might just have blocked the whole web page rendering sequence.

When I not fresh page, just normal explore routes, the loading message is not updated at all. Always, the first message "loading".

What is the right way to do such thing?

Comment: Since you're doing DOM manipulation, that's probably outside of Angular's scope. You should use `$apply` to notify Angular
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

Comment: The [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) does not work with `<h3>` tags. What are you trying to accomplishing with that?